Min-cost perfect matching, but must pick exactly k special edges. Is it NP-hard?
I'd like to know if the following generalization of min-cost perfect matching is NP-hard.
As usual, we are given a graph $G = (V,E)$ with costs on edges $c: E \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. In addition, there is a given set of 'special' edges $R \subseteq E$ and an integer $k$.
The goal is to find the subset of edges $F \subseteq E$ of minimum cost such that:

every vertex has degree 1 in $(V,F)$, and
there are exactly $k$ special edges in $F$. That is, $|F \cap R| = k$.

Is this in $P$? Is it NP-hard? Both ;)?

It seems that it should be reducible to Exact Weight perfect matching, at least for poly-bounded weights. Perhaps this article is relevant. https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.13899

This is exactly the (in)famous Exact Matching problem introduced by Papadimitriou & Yannakakis in

The complexity of restricted spanning tree problems. Journal of the ACM (JACM), 29(2):285–309, 1982.

The complexity deciding whether a perfect (maximum) matching with exactly k red edges exist, in not known.

It is known to be in randomized poly-time.

@ChandraChekuri I think you mean RNC^2 through the Isolation Lemma?

Obtaining randomized parallel algorithms is one application of the isolation lemma. For the exact matching problem it shows a randomized poly-time algorithm. See arxiv.org/abs/2203.13899  for instance.

So what about the optimization variant that was asked about? You can get a randomized pseudo-polynomial algoritm with standard methods (I believe), but what about the min-cost version with exponentially large weights?
